# Changing permission for 'Public' folder always failed

Tags: permissions, samba, file-sharing, chmod

I have 2 PC using ubuntu(I assume PC 1 and PC 2), and I always share a file or folder for each other. I know that I have to right click first, choose `Sharing Options` and check `Share this folder`.

After that I change their permission to **777**. `sudo chmod 777 Public/ -R`

PC 1 always running correctly, but not for PC 2. There is an error something like this : `chmod: cannot access 'Public/': No such file or directory`

eventually sharing will work for just only PC 1 which share a file and access it from PC 2. But PC 2 cannot share its file. Where is the mistake? and how do I solve this problem?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Can you confirm that the Public directory *actually exists* on PC 2? The `chmod` output is quite explicit that it doesn't.

Comment: I was very sure that Public folder already exists. That's in Home -> Public

Comment: Are you sure as well that it is a directory?  Please show the output of `file Public`. Also, put options before arguments. The `-R` should come right after `chmod`.